# ayuda con los constrains en una table view en swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints

tengo el siguiente problema con las tablas 
estoy creando una table view personaliza 
le agregue una imagen y un titulo
estoy cargando las imágenes desde una clase y me carga todo bien la imagen 
y el titulo
pero al momento de visualizarlo en el simulador se ve de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y yo quiero que sea vea como esta en el Xcode 
en el prototype cells
a la imagen le puse constrains de 0,0,0,0 y aparece así de feo
pero si borro los contrains aparece como en el Xcode un poco mas chico :(

Comment: Buenas bienvenido a **StackOverflow** en español por favor antes de preguntar primero ve [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y revisa también [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) edita tu pregunta y mejorarla para tener una respuesta que realmente te ayude.

Comment: Solo con la información que aportas te diría que le pongas un height a la tabla

Answer (score 0):

Cuando usas celdas personalizadas en ocasiones debes agregar todas las constantes posibles para todos los objetos y de esa manera hacer que la celda se adapte al tamaño de los objetos que contiene.

Intenta agregando un View a la celda, ajusta sus margenes y luego dentro de esta misma agrega la imagen y el titulo.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu problema es que la imagen de fondo se escapa de la celda, prueba  dejando desde el IBuilder seleccionando el *Category Image* la propiedad `Content Mode = AspectFill`y seleccionando la propiedad `Drawing Clip to Bounds`

Answer (score 0):

Pudes agregar la siguiente función a tu código y eso pondría en todas las celdas de tu tableView al mismo tamaño de alto. Ya dentro de tu celda tendrías que manejar los constraints adecuados

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return 100 // Aquí va el tamaño que quieres que tenga tu celda 
}
```